# Can an automatic close vote question message be added for "belongs to another site"?

Tags: feature-request, comments, migration

I am looking for the stackoverflow LaTeX tag to migrate questions to https://tex.stackexchange.com/. Almost all questions with that tag have to be migrated to tex.SE. Always when I see that, I leave a comment to inform the person who asked the question that the question was "flagged" to be moved.

I know that for close votes because of duplicate questions there are automatic comments. I think a short automatic comment like

> Hello [username] and Welcome to StackExchange. StackExchange has several
>   sub-sites (like StackOverflow) that are about different topics. The
>   kind of question you have asked should probably rather be asked on
>   tex.stackexchange.com. Your question was flagged for migration. You
>   don't need to do anything.

would be nice for site migration votes, too. The first two sentences should eventually only be added if the person has less than 100 points.

Would it be possible to implement that?

Comment: Only high-quality questions should be migrated, however. I doubt that *all* posts on SO for the LaTeX tag fit that description.

Comment: And note that you should only flag to migrate **off-topic** posts. Are the posts you flag *explicitly off-topic* for Stack Overflow? Some overlap in subject is fine; separate sites have separate *communities and culture*, so overlap in subject should be judged where the post will be a better cultural fit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I didn't know that. However, I think it is difficult to determine what a "high quality question" is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Regarding your second question - yes, the questions I flag are off-topic. They are not about programming, but about how to use LaTeX (for simple programs like finding a symbol / creating a non-trivial table, not for programming LaTeX)

Comment: Rule-of-thumb for quality: Would you upvote the question if it appeared on Tex.SE? If so, it is of suitable quality.